# How do I replace a letter in a string without .replace In Java

Tags: java

I need help finishing this code. I'm trying to go through every letter in a word and changing the letterToReplace with the replacingLetter.  The problem is that I can't use .replace

Please help

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, char letterToReplace, char replacingLetter)
{
    String ans = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        char current = word.charAt(i);
        if(current == letterToReplace)
        {
           letterToReplace = replacingLetter;
        }
        ans += Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to update and print `current`:

```
if(current == letterToReplace)
{
   current = replacingLetter;
}
ans += Character.toString(current);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I don't quite understand... What do you mean by updating current?

Comment: Ohhh sorry, I didn't see the difference. Thank you!